# What can be put in an EJB stereotype?

Tags: annotations, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, stereotype

We're migrating an EJB 3.0 application to EJB 3.1 and would like to use `@Stereotype` to reduce some of the EJB configuration.

The annotations we plan to have are:

- [@Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html)
- [@ConcurrencyManagement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ConcurrencyManagement.html)([BEAN](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ConcurrencyManagementType.html#BEAN))
- [@PermitAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.html)
- [@Interceptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/Interceptors.html) or custom [@InterceptorBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InterceptorBinding.html) annotation
- @SecurityDomain("acme") JBoss / PicketLink

Of those I know that `@Singleton` can't be put into a `@Stereotype` and has to be on the EJB itself. What else can't be put into a `@Stereotype`?

### Update

The specification [[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhqc.html)], [[2](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/stereotypes.html)] says that

> A stereotype encapsulates any combination of:
>
> - default scope, and
> - a set of interceptor bindings.

The examples then use Java EE 7 `@Transactional` which is an `@InterceptorBinding` which leads me to believe that none of the above annotations can be put into a stereotype.

Answer (score 1):

The [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhqc.html) states the following:

> A stereotype is a kind of annotation, applied to a bean, that
>   incorporates other annotations. Stereotypes can be particularly useful
>   in large applications where you have a number of beans that perform
>   similar functions. A stereotype is a kind of annotation that specifies
>   the following:
>
> - A default scope
> - Zero or more interceptor bindings
> - Optionally, a @Named annotation, guaranteeing default EL naming
> - Optionally, an @Alternative annotation, specifying that all beans with this stereotype are alternatives

So as you saw yourself, the annotations you used are not in one of the mentioned groups.

My personal suggestion is, to be careful with creating and using stereotypes, since one then always have to know (or check) what it means, so for example I prefer using `@Named @RequestScoped` rather than `@Model` because saving one line of code does not make up to not see the scope at the first glance.

Comment: We talk about saving at least five lines of code eighty times. Not to mention that we could then change things in a single point instead of sed-ing the whole code base and missing five places. The same argument would prevent us from using interfaces because when you use an interface you don't know which method will be called.

Comment: You are right about changing in one place. As I sad, I would recommend to use it carefully, not to avoid it. Concerning interfaces, sadly one still observes many usages of a 1:1 relation between interfaces and classes, which does not make sense if it's not likely that one has a second implementation of the interface very soon.